# AttributeError: module 'calendar' has no attribute 'isleap'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import calendar
print(calendar.isleap(2016))
```

My python version is 3.5.2 and when I run the above command I get the following error:

> -AttributeError: module 'calendar' has no attribute 'isleap'

Using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: did you call the file or a neighbour "calendar.py" ?

Comment: I did not call calender.py the file being called is datetime.py inside which calendar is being imported

Comment: datetime is a builtin module too, rename it to something else.

Comment: renamed the file its still not working

Comment: whats the new name ?

Comment: just type `print calendar` and see from where the module is called.

Comment: the above program is now working

Comment: the problem is i have saved all my programs inside one directory and when i run the command "python3 filename.py " inside the directory, it is compiling all the programs not just the individual file

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem (and the same version of Python). Try to place your code (except import of course) into the function. It could look like:

```
import calendar

def leap(year):
    return calendar.isleap(year)

print(leap(2016))
```

Comment: Since I cannot reproduce @Kanav Malik error, I am unable to check, but what you suggest is very unlikely to solve the issue.